# How can I query empty tables to check emptiness?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following database structure.

```
applets
--id (incr)

applet_stats
--id (incr)
--applet_id (relates to applet.id)
--date ("Y-m-d" format)
```

Example data:

```
applets
1
2
3

applet_stats
1   1    2015.01.15
2   1    2015.01.15
3   1    2015.01.15
4   1    2015.01.15
5   2    2015.01.14
```

In the above example, we have 3 applets. Applet 1 has 4x statistics on 2015.01.15, Applet 2 1x  statistics on 2015.01.14 (yesterday)

How can I query the database so I get the following output:

```
// Show me the applets which doesn't have any statistics on "2015.01.15".
[2,3]
```

I tried it myself using leftJoin but I'm overlooking something very simple so I get wrong result each time.

Ps. Would be even better in an Eloquent statement.

Comment: Show us the query you tried.

Comment: It is an Eloquent statement, and I just closed that file without saving after the frustration. If you want, I can get it from the ST2 cache.

Comment: OK, show us the statement.

Comment: Have you set up the relationship in your models?

Answer (score 2):

Eloquent way, assumings `stats` is `hasMany` relation:

```
$date = '2015-01-15';

Applet::whereDoesntHave('stats', function ($q) use ($date) {
   $q->where('date', $date);
})->get();
```

Comment: It's actually `whereDoesntHave()`

Comment: It doesn't have hasMany, just belongsTo('Applet');

Comment: You got me wrong @Aristona - `stats` is a relation method on the `Applet` (it is `hasMany`, I just wanted to emphasize the name assumption)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id 
from applets
where id not in(select distinct applet_id from applet_stats where date ='2015.01.15')
```

this may helps you